# Can't Login to MVC app when debugging in VS2012, Can when attaching to process

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here.

I have an MVC application and am using standard forms authentication.  When I debug in VS2012, my login screen doesn't seem to work - I am never able to login using a valid un/pw.  However, if I use IIS and attach to the IIS process, everything seems to work fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had set the following in my web.config to enable single sign on:

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" domain="ngkflocal.com" />  
    </authentication>
```

by removing the "domain" attribute everything started working again.